# bash scripting: Can I get sed to output the original line, then a space, then the modified line?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I'm new to Unix in all its forms, so please go easy on me!
I have a bash script that will pipe an ls command with arbitrary filenames into sed, which will use an arbitrary replacement pattern on the files, and then this will be piped into awk for some processing. The catch is, awk needs to know both the original file name and the new one.

I've managed everything except getting the original file names into awk. For instance, let's say my files are test.* and my replacement pattern is 's:es:ar;', which would change every occurrence of "test" to "tart". For testing purposes I'm just using awk to print what it's receiving:

```
ls "$@" | sed "$pattern" | awk '{printf "0: %s\n1: %s\n2: %s\n", $0,$1,$2}'
```

where test.* is in $@ and the pattern is stored in $pattern.
Clearly, this doesn't get me to where I want to be. The output is obviously

```
0: tart.c
1: tart.c
2:
```

If I could get sed to output "test.c tart.c", then I'd have two parameters for awk. I've played around with the pattern to no avail, even hardcoding "test.c" into the replacement. But of course that just gave me amateur results like "ttest.c art.c". Is it possible for sed to remember the input, then work it into the beginning of the output? Do I even have the right ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The simplest thing is... everything you can do in **sed** you can do in **awk** - and if you combine your scripts, your work in the end will be both faster and more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to change the first t in a b in the duplicated field.

Duplicate (`&` replays the matched part), change first word and swap (remember 2 strings with a space in between):

```
echo test.c |  sed -r 's/.*/& &/;s/t/b/;s/([^ ]*) (.*)/\2 \1/'
```

or with more magic (copy original value to buffer, make the change, insert value from buffer as the first line and replace eond of line with a space)

```
echo test.c |  sed 'h;s/t/b/;x;G;s/\n/ /'
```

Comment: @VivekVK I added some explanation. 2 years later I think the `awk` solution is better, with some basic knowledge of  `awk` you will understand what the code does. The `sed` solution does require an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use Perl instead of sed:

```
echo test.c | perl -lne 'print "$_ ", s/es/ar/r'
```

`-l` removes the newline from input and adds it after each `print`. The `/r` modifier to the substitution returns the modified string instead of changing the variable (Perl 5.14+ needed).

Old answer, not working for `s/t/b/2` or `s/.*/replaced/2`:

<strike>You can duplicate the contents of the line with `s/.*/& &/`, then just tell sed that it should only apply the second substitution (this works at least in GNU sed):</strike>

```
echo test.c | sed 's/.*/& &/; s/es/ar/2'
```

Comment: Thank you! I found some test cases that don't work as expected...With "s/.*/& &/; s/t/b/2" I expect "test.c best.c" but it actually does "tesb.c test.c". Am I wrong about that? And with "s/.*/replaced/2" I think it should be "test.c replaced" but it shows "test.c test.c". My regex interpretation could be mistaken...

Comment: Check the update. `s/t/b/2` changes the second `t` to `b`, so it can't work.

Comment: This is for a homework assignment all about sed and awk, unfortunately. Maybe I'm going about it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo 'foo' | awk '{old=$0; gsub(/o/,"e"); print old, $0}'
foo fee
```